# Cloudfront URL never expires

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudfront, pre-signed-url

Scenerio:
I am trying to generate cloudfront signed urls to objects in s3.

STEPS:
 1. created an object in s3 bucket and made it public.
 2. created a cloudfront distribution pointing to that s3 bucket.
 3. generated the signed url using the code below

The following is the code to generate cloudfront signed urls from their [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudfront.html#generate-a-signed-url-for-amazon-cloudfront).

```
import datetime

from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from botocore.signers import CloudFrontSigner


def rsa_signer(message):
    with open('path/to/key.pem', 'rb') as key_file:
        private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
        key_file.read(),
        password=None,
        backend=default_backend()
       )
    return private_key.sign(message, padding.PKCS1v15(), hashes.SHA1())

key_id = 'AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE'
url = 'https://d2949o5mkkp72v.cloudfront.net/hello.txt'
expire_date = datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1)

cloudfront_signer = CloudFrontSigner(key_id, rsa_signer)

# Create a signed url that will be valid until the specfic expiry date
# provided using a canned policy.
signed_url = cloudfront_signer.generate_presigned_url(url, date_less_than=expire_date)
print(signed_url)
```

output:

```
https://d2949o5mkkp72v.cloudfront.net/hello.txt?Expires=1483228800&Signature=some_signature&Key-Pair-Id=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
```

The above url is pointing to a date back in time but I am still able to access the object via this URL. Also I can access the object by truncating the Signature and Key-Pair-Id query params.

What could have gone wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem. The error was actually not in the code but in the configuration of cloudfront distribution.

The following configuration was missing:
[image: cloudfront signed url config option]

Hopefully it helps :)

If editing the configuration for an already existing distribution, you'll find this "Restrict Viewer Access" setting within the edit settings of a behavior record within the "behaviors" tab.
[image]

Comment: I have followed same procedure but it doesnot work for date and time . ```expire_date = datetime(2022, 4, 2,11,33)```. The url valid works for 4/2 whole day even after  expires date. How to avoid this problem?